# how to fix filesystem of a LXC container

Tags: lxc, fsck

This container doen't start anymore with these errors messages :

```
# lxc-start -n deb7 -F
INIT: version 2.88 booting
Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
Cleaning up temporary files... /tmp.
Mount point '/proc/sysrq-trigger' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/console' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/ptmx' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/tty1' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/tty2' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/tty3' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Mount point '/dev/tty4' does not exist. Skipping mount. ... (warning).
Activating lvm and md swap...done.
Checking file systems...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
failed (code 139).
File system check failed. A log is being saved in /var/log/fsck/checkfs if that location is writable. Please repair the file system manually. ... failed!
A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and resume system boot. ... (warning).
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue): 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Attempt to start maintenance shell failed. Continuing with system boot in 5 seconds. ... failed!
```

configuration:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:61:07

lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/var/lib/lxc/deb7/rootfs

# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf

# Container specific configuration
lxc.tty.max = 4
lxc.uts.name = deb7
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.pty.max = 1024
```

Other containers on the same machine are fine, only this one doesn't start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same problem with a debian wheezy container on my arch linux host machine.
Also it was not possible to create a new debian wheezy container (other debian versions worked).
After switching from kernel 4.15.2-2 to 4.14.18-1-lts the problem was gone.

UPDATE:
open /etc/default/grub and add vsyscall=emulate to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameters, then execute
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
or update-grub on ubuntu, restart, party.